# Do more registers increase clock cycle time?

Tags: cpu, performance

While reading a book on computer organization, I ran into a design principle stating that "smaller is faster", indicating that fewer registers means less clock cycle time. Could you prove why?

Comment: Here is a simple way to think about it: More registers = bigger circuit = more time for the information to go through it

Comment: @nirshahar to go through what ? (not to be mean , just need more clarification ).

Comment: The CPU is composed of logic gates. Having more logic gates, means that we need a bigger logical circuit for the CPU. Actually, it will also mean we need a *longer* circuit for the CPU. This means, that it will increase the time in order for a signal to go through a certain part in the CPU, which means that we need a longer clock cycle so things won't mess up.

Comment: By the way, modern CPUs often have more physical registers than they have architectural registers, to reduce hazards. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming

Answer (score 1):

There’s no “proof”. What you can do is try out different technologies and see that with every technology that you try the same thing happens.

Assume you work at Intel, which produces billions of processors with 16 integer registers. And you are the bright spark who decides that it would be better to have 32 integer registers. There are tons of changes to the processor to be made. One is “store some value into register k, for 0 <= k < 16” vs. “For 0 <= k < 32”.

You will find that the register file has twice the physical size, so data has to be transmitted over a longer distance, then the speed of light or more importantly the speed of an electrical signal moving through silicon comes into it, and more distance = more time. You will also find that the hardware picking one of 16 registers still leaves you with a choice of two out of 32 registers, so more time is needed. And the guys at Intel designing their chips have seen that over and over again over the last 50 years.

A shorter explanation is TANSTAAFL. Which is a universal law.

Comment: X86 has a limited number of architectural registers, but have a very large number of physical registers (200-300 for high end Intel processors). The architectural registers are assigned to physical registers dynamically using a technique called register renaming; part of Tomasulo's algorithm.

Comment: @pveentjer And that changes the principles how?